# ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment

Tags: java, eclipse, jdwp

I get this error after debugging in Eclipse. The debug is successful though.

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: I face the exact same problem from within NetBeans 6.1 when attempting to debug into a piece of code that uses both the network, and image API.  Were you trying to use either the network, or image API by any chance?

Comment: I was not using the Image API, for sure. What do you mean by using the network? I was using sockets if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yep; network APIs is what i meant - Sockets/Http

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476706 which has low priority and is still not fixed. Definitely a Mustang bug but no clear explanation (seems to occur pretty randomly according to the bug reporters on top of that).

Comment: On that URL I get a message "This bug is not available."  Is the bug number correct?  Or has the bug been removed?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster, the bug shows up for me, along with details about it.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses And now it's back :D

Comment: Glad to see that as of November 2015, this is still not fixed.

Comment: Hello! Man from 2018 here. I just faced the bug :p

Comment: Hello from 2019, need less to say I came here after getting the same error

Comment: 2019 April still its not fixed

Comment: Love the resolution in the link `Resolution: Won't Fix` :D

Comment: Jan 2020 Still not Fixed :/
Also another project in the same eclipse work-space with same configurations work..

Comment: Greetings from March 2024. Still not fixed and the status has been set to "won't fix".

Answer (score 82):

Just add `System.exit(0);`   to the end of your main method.

That's all you have to do.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked. But then I took it out, and it still worked. From the accepted solution above it appears it could be a timing issue which makes this very hard to reproduce faithfully all the time.

Comment: This works for me.. I'm also running java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)

Comment: I get the same result as @Xonatron. Weird!

Comment: sounds like fixing a threading issue by adding sleep here and there

Comment: @Xonatron What if the error is not throwing from the main class ?

Answer (score 5):

It's apparently a JVM bug. It's harmless and unpredictable.

Comment: Hmm, not so harmless, it caused my program to spontaneously fail.

Comment: Um, generally it means 'something else caused your program to fail' and then it does this on the way out, but I suppose there could be something new.

Comment: It is supposed to happen during the shutdown of the JVM.  So your program was done anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Happens on something as simple as this tutorial

```
//trim spaces
String s2 = "Welcome!";
int len1 = s2.length();
System.out.println(len1);
String s3 = s2.trim();
System.out.println(s3.length());
```

Happens if run program too fast multiple times so something to do with system performance?

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Everyone I'm facing this problem using the image API reading and writing files over the network, when I run the program working with local files this doesn't happen. After verifiying my results I confirmed that it really doesn't do any harm (at least on my debugging). Now that I'm reading this post I stopped looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this occurs when I am using a workspace stored on my USB drive and sometimes on my work's network. It is not a major issue and doesnt seem to have any effect on the execution of any of my programs. I tested @Vasile Surdu's solution of adding`System.exit(0);` to the end of the main method and it works. `Another solution is to restart eclipse` which works for me most of the time.