# 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ignoreMethodBodies' Exception while creating AST

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

While passing a java source code to the below mentioned code, I get an exception and have no idea how to fix this. Kindlly let me know where I am wrong/ any alternative solution...

Source Code:

```
char[] source = resultEntryIndustry.text.toCharArray();
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);  
parser.setSource(source);
Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
CompilationUnit cUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

Exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ignoreMethodBodies
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.parse(CompilationUnitResolver.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:1194)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:801)
at itjava.model.CompilationUnitStoreIndustry.createCompilationUnitFacadeList(CompilationUnitStoreIndustry.java:71)
at itjava.presenter.WordInfoPresenterIndustry.SetCompilationUnitListAndAccessRepository(WordInfoPresenterIndustry.java:162)
at itjava.industry.code2String.main(code2String.java:31)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

The source code parsed is a simple java file used to connect to database using JDBC.

Comment: Refer this previous question. It may help.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment

Comment: The qn. u posted is totally different from this.. Wrong link maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing an almost [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995209/exception-while-generating-ast-using-eclipse-jdt-sdk-in-a-non-eclipse-environmen) and found the fix. Whatever environment you're running the code in, it has some component in its classpath which is not compatible with jdt core.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. I removed ecj.jar from my Apache/lib and it fine works now.