# JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment

Tags: java

what does this mean and what do I do to fix it? Any and all ideas are much appreciated!

```
"ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183): [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

"Thanks in advance!
after giving the output in the console of the ecclipse the above statement is shown too but if i debug it second time than the msg is not shown!!!!!!!!!
connection created
true

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData@31dcf0
13, 0, 0000-00-00, , , Guwahati, 2013-05-23, , , Open, 2, 2013-05-23 01:47:54
14, 1, 2013-05-28, Own Vehicle, , Guwahati, 2013-05-27, , AS 25AC 3816, Open, 2, 2013-05-27 03:51:53
15, 1, 2013-05-29, Own Vehicle, , Guwahati, 2013-05-28, , AS 25AC  3816, Open, 2, 2013-05-28 03:20:57
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]
```

Comment: plz rply i will be greatful to you

Answer (score 2):

This is a known JVM bug but is low priority. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476706

There is some more information from [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment)