# ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2 JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183): [util.c:840]

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, debugging

I just got a very simple algorithm for calculating the effort of a binary search. And when executed it a few times to get an average, following error appeared:

```
    ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
    JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
```

So now I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment) thread, that it's a unsolved [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6476706) from oracle. Which randomly occoures and which will not be fixed in the near future.

So my question is: is there any way to avoid this (and other bugs like this), like any exception handling magic, which is till now unknown for me ?

Comment: Are you trying to access shared mutable state in illegal fashion? share your code to able to help.