# Big double values gives error for java 1.8?

Tags: java

Below code snippet gives error for 1.0E27%10 this arithmetic operation

```
"ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
```

And the code is

```
int []A = {1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000};
int cnt=0;
double product = 1;
for(int i= A.length-1 ;  cnt < 3; i--,cnt++ ) {
     product*=A[i];
}
System.out.println(product%10); //// 1.0E27%10
while(product%10 == 0) {
    product = product/10;
    zeroCnt++;
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  It is most likely a bug in the JVM. I would try a newer update.

Comment: BTW This prints `2.0` for me.  I suspect that `double` isn't you should be using as it only has about 16 digits of accuracy not 27. I suggest you use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: what is the use of `cnt` in `for(int i= A.length-1 ;  cnt < 3; i--,cnt++ )`? Can't you just check if `i >= 0`?

Comment: I'll try Bigdecimal

Answer (score 1):

This is an [old JVM bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment), rather than an error with doubles.
Try updating Java or adding

```
System.exit(0);
```

at the end of your code.